# Jquery and PHP GET function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How can I make jquery run that `$_GET`. I'm trying to remove "Refreshing a page" and that is why I'm trying to use jQuery.

```
if (isset($_GET['add'])) {
    global $db;
    $quantity = $db->query('SELECT id, quantity FROM data WHERE id = '.$_GET['add']);
    while ($r = $quantity->fetch()) {
        if ($r['quantity'] != $_SESSION['data_'.(int)$_GET['add']]) {
            $_SESSION['data_'.(int)$_GET['add']]+= '1';
        }
    }
```

```
<script>
$( ".wasd" ).click(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $( "<div>" )
        .append( "$_GET add function" )
        .appendTo( "#log" );
});
</script>
```

Comment: You need jquery AJAX to send the request. Not just jquery.

Comment: SQL-injection in your code. Never pass user input directly to DB query.

Comment: Haha the question was closed just as I was preparing an answer :D

Answer (score 0):

Example ajax get request using jQuery:

```
$.get( "url_of_php_here?add=" + id, function( data ) {
      $( ".result" ).html( data );
      alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```